# Blueimp gallery inside relative container is overlapped by fixed blocks

Tags: javascript, html, css, image-gallery

I prepared a **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mx6t44xk/1/)** to show you some interesting thing. This demo contains basic [blueimp gallery setup example](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery#setup), nav bar and button.

```
<div class="nav">nav</div>

<div class="wrapper">

  <div id="links">
    <a href="images/banana.jpg" title="Banana">
      <img src="images/thumbnails/banana.jpg" class="image" alt="Banana">
    </a>
    <a href="images/apple.jpg" title="Apple">
      <img src="images/thumbnails/apple.jpg" class="image" alt="Apple">
    </a>
    <a href="images/orange.jpg" title="Orange">
      <img src="images/thumbnails/orange.jpg" class="image" alt="Orange">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery">
    <div class="slides"></div>
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <a class="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="next">›</a>
    <a class="close">×</a>
    <a class="play-pause"></a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
  </div>

</div>

<button type="button" class="button">Click Me</button>
```

When user click image, it opens and occupies the full screen, but **if**`.wrapper` **has a relative position**, image won't be occupies full screen, because nav bar will overlap the image.

Try it yourself.

1. Open demo.
2. Click image.
3. Close image.
4. Click button.
5. Click image.

After that you will see, nav bar will overlap the image.

How to fix that problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When You are making div relative, You are also adding `z-index: 1` to it - and You navbar has `z-index: 10` already, so that's the main cause of such behavior.

Try adding `z-index` greater than 10 to relative div in Your stylesheet:

```
  &_relative {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 11;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! I just thought that block with fixed position can have any `z-index` regardless of the parent block. Now I understand, if parent block has `z-index: 10`, all his children will be under parent even if children have `z-index` over 10

Comment: exactly like that ;)